# Python - Geotext - Cities like "Rio de Janeiro" are not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, data-mining, geotext

I'm trying to use GeoText to genrate country mentions, but cities like Rio de Janeiro, Rio das Ostras are not recognized.
I verified the dictionary and those cities are OK in there.

- Input:

`text = "Rio de Janeiro, Las Vegas, New York"
geo = GeoText(text)
print(geo.cities)`

- Output:

  - ['Las Vegas', 'New York']
- Expected Output:

  - ['Rio de Janeiro','Las Vegas','New York']

Using python 3.x and geotext 0.3.0

Comment: Please provide a working example of what you want to do. It will be much easier for someone to help you that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex on the GitHub repo and the latest pip installed version (`0.3.0`) are different.

```
In[2]: import re
In[3]: text = "Rio de Janeiro, Las Vegas, New York"

# old regex (pip installed)
In[4]: city_regex = r"[A-Z]+[a-zà-ú]*(?:[ '-][A-Z]+[a-zà-ú]*)*"
In[5]: re.findall(city_regex, text)
Out[5]: ['Rio', 'Janeiro', 'Las Vegas', 'New York']

# new regex (GitHub)
In[6]: city_regex = r"[A-ZÀ-Ú]+[a-zà-ú]+[ \-]?(?:d[a-u].)?(?:[A-ZÀ-Ú]+[a-zà-ú]+)*"
In[7]: re.findall(city_regex, text)
Out[7]: ['Rio de Janeiro', 'Las Vegas', 'New York']
```

The GitHub repos regex seems to work fine even for three word cities but it isn't being used in the latest version on PyPI.